# Angular-translate $partialLoader and $urlLoader

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I've implemented `$partialLoader` with static files and works really good, but the documentation about the use of `$useUrlLoader` and `$partialLoader` it's not really clear for me.

**This is my code:**

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader(http://miweb.com/rest/lang);
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('EN');
```

Now, I need to integrate it with $partialLoader. My question is: How can I use $partialLoader with $useUrlLoader? How Can I pass parameters for the specific sections?

**This is the code from the docs:**

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: '/i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'
});
```

Can I use the code above with useUrlLoader?

Any light in the dark will be appreciated. I don't know how `$useUrlLoader` works with `$partiaLoader` and the documentation is not saying anything about it.

Comment: Hi. From where do you want to take the json files for the language? From an external server or same domain?